Mounting a bathroom mirror cabinet with only one stud near top-center
I'm trying to mount a mirror cabinet over my sink. It weighs about 40lbs with the mirror doors attached and has a cross bar at the top for mounting: https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/p/enhet-mirror-cb-with-2-doors-gray-s69434656/. I've located a stud near the center. I plan on screwing in 4 screws into the stud in the center and using these plastic toggle anchors on the sides (1 each) https://toggler.com/products/toggler-plastic-toggle-anchors. Is that enough? Should I be worried about wires or piping above the sink? First timer.
Thanks!

Along the stud, there should be no issue. As for the toggle bolts, drill the wall slowly and carefully before attaching the cabinet, to check for wires and plumbing. One might use an endoscope or dental mirror to check inside the wall cavity, but if the first hole had no issue, another plumbed vertically in line with it likely would be OK.

As long as one of the stud screws goes through the nailer strip, you should be fine.  Use a washer under the screw head to spread the load.
